# Travis CI won't compile in release, libs not found

Tags: c++, g++, travis-ci

Travis CI won't compile in release but compile fine in debug, I get these errors:

`Linking TealDemo
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraCore.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraGraphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraUtility.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraGraphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraRenderer.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraGraphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraNoise.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraNetwork.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraPhysics.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraGraphics.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraLua.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../../../lib/gmake/x64/libNazaraAudio.so, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libNazaraSDK.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

But every libs are in the archive and are moved to `/usr/lib/`
Travis CI build: https://travis-ci.org/S6066/Teal/jobs/173483445
.travis.yml: https://github.com/S6066/Teal/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding RelativeLinks flag it premake5.lua worked